# Why are delegate & on not working for jquery selectmenu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

If I go from jQuery 1.6 to 1.7 a line like:

```
$('#form').delegate( 'select', 'selectmenuopen', function() {});
```

will not fire my callback. Any ideas? If I bind directly to a select it still works.

I know there is a git repo of the latest selectmenu that is different than the one in dev for UI 1.9 but I can't remember where it is sadly.

I should have mentioned I did try "on" with no luck.

**NOTE**
The selectmenu plugin extends `$.ui.widget` and internally calls `._trigger( "open" )` which will add the prefix of the plugin, therefore making `"selectmenuopen"` the right event to look for. Binding works perfectly proving this is the right event.

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.7, you should consider using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on), which replaces `live()`, `delegate()` and `bind()`. All you need to do to convert to `on()` (apart from change the function name ;), is swap the order of the first 2 parameters.

Comment: Sorry didn't mention I tried that too. Updated post.

Comment: `delegate`, `bind`, `live` all call `on` anyway, it doesn't matter

Comment: Curses, that thickens the plot! Are you sure the events aren't namespaced or anything, like selectmenu.open (grasping at straws here...)? Can you link to the git you're looking at?

Comment: I'm positive my lines of code are fine as going back down to 1.6 solved my issue. I had also tried upgrading jquery-ui to the latest along with jquery to see if some widget change would fix this.

Comment: It's worth noting jQuery 1.7 calls the .on method when you use .delegate but 1.6 calls .live. In 1.7 .live is aliased to .on, so you can't really call the old .live method anymore, which is what's happening when you revert to 1.6 even though the method name you're using doesn't change. Any console errors or anything throughout this?

Comment: Nope there were no errors. I ended up reverting to 1.6 as my app was still fine on it. I'm planning on updating back to 1.7 once selectmenu is ready from UI 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to answer this when I found answer... I had to upgrade jQuery UI by one version to work properly with jQuery 1.7. It's still strange to me that every other plugin was working perfect except this one so I didn't notice for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery 1.7 you should use `on` rather than `delegate`:

```
$('#form').on('selectmenuopen', 'select', function() {
   // your code
});
```

[More information on `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: That is the wrong syntax for on. You mean $('#form').on( 'selectmenuopen', 'select', callback );

Comment: Woops yes... as per the API documentation that I'd linked to myself Doh!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written your code, you're binding to a custom event named 'selectmenuopen'

The best thing to do is make sure that you're doing something like

```
jQuery(document).trigger('selectmenuopen');
```

or

```
jQuery('#form').trigger('selectmenuopen');
```

or the event will never fire.

Comment: Please see above note I just added